# pushViewController doesn't work from unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a UITableViewController with an unwind segue set up to trigger when we navigate back from a settings view controller.

In the unwind segue method, I'm checking if I should logout and present login screen.

I also have a logout button that always logs user out and presents login screen.

```
- (IBAction)logoutButton:(id)sender {
    [self logout];
    ReusableLoginViewController *loginVCiPhone = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ReusableLogin_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReusableLogin_iPhone_Standard"];
    UINavigationController *rootNav = self.navigationController;
    [rootNav.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
    [rootNav pushViewController:loginVCiPhone animated:NO];
}


- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

  SettingsViewController *source = (SettingsViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
  if (source.apiRootURL) {
    // Do some stuff with source.apiRootURL
    [self logoutButton:nil];
  }
}
```

The logoutButton works perfectly when called directly from a button, but the pushViewController function doesn't push my ReusableLoginViewController when called from the unwind segue.
The [rootNav.navigationBar setHidden:YES] does execute.
Does anybody know what is going on here?

Comment: I have the same issue but my new view is momentarily displayed and then removed